# What kind of model should I use?

Tags: predictive-modeling, marketing

I am working with a dataset with about 10,000 customers. About 3,000 engaged with dozens of marketing campaigns over the years.

I am trying to create a model to find which marketing campaign to use on a given customer. I was thinking of creating affinity scores based on conversions from these campaigns and do some sort of random forest/logistic regression. It gets tricky because only 3,000 have engaged and I am not sure what to recommend for the other 7,000. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an unsupervised method such as clustering to group users, then assign  marketing campaigns that have been used by others within the same cluster.

Comment: thanks, but let's say in cluster one, there are dozens of campaigns that were successful for those customers. which campaign do you then choose?

Comment: The most common/successful ones